# Lay out an image on a Qt dialog

Tags: c++, qt

How to add an image to a dialog in Qt?

I know this has been often asked in the past and most answers come up with a `QLabel` and its `setPixmap` member. However, this usually is not what the user (me) intends:

- A `QLabel` with a pixmap set does not participate in the surrounding `QLayout`. That is, it simply refuses to resize when the dialog is resized, like e.g., a `QPushButton` would do. Two `QPushButton`s next to each other in a `QHorizontalLayout` will (something like) equally divide the available horizontal space between them. A `QLabe` with a pixmap next to a `QPushButton` in the same layout will just stay fixed in size.
- By default, a naked `QLabel` won't resize its contents when it's resized.
- But when it does (`QLabel::setResizeContents`) it won't keep aspect ratio.

Is there any *native* way to have a pixmap shown on a dialog and have it reasonably *participate in the layout*?

Comment: your question is broad.

Comment: I don't think so. Why do you?

Comment: You can try graphics scene view framework. Add image as a pixel map item into a scene.

Comment: @m.c. This won't do anything to help here.

Comment: I think your question has to be rephrased, because what you ask for is very specific: you want an extending widget that displays a proportionally scaled image and maintains its aspect ratio. Your definition of "reasonable participation in a layout" is too vague to be useful as the topic of the question.

Comment: Probably... The issue turned out to be more frustrating than I expected. So I finally came up with this question on how to _simply put the damn image there and behave well_ :-)

Answer (score 0):

Item resizing can be managed via `sizePolicy` property. From [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop):

> sizePolicy : QSizePolicy
>
> This property holds the default layout behavior of the widget.
>
> If there is a QLayout that manages this widget's children, the size
>   policy specified by that layout is used. If there is no such QLayout,
>   the result of this function is used.
>
> The default policy is Preferred/Preferred, which means that the widget
>   can be freely resized, but prefers to be the size sizeHint() returns.
>   Button-like widgets set the size policy to specify that they may
>   stretch horizontally, but are fixed vertically. The same applies to
>   lineedit controls (such as QLineEdit, QSpinBox or an editable
>   QComboBox) and other horizontally orientated widgets (such as
>   QProgressBar). QToolButton's are normally square, so they allow growth
>   in both directions. Widgets that support different directions (such as
>   QSlider, QScrollBar or QHeader) specify stretching in the respective
>   direction only. Widgets that can provide scroll bars (usually
>   subclasses of QScrollArea) tend to specify that they can use
>   additional space, and that they can make do with less than sizeHint().

I think you are searching for `QSizePolicy::Expanding` size policy:

> The sizeHint() is a sensible size, but the widget can be shrunk and
>   still be useful. The widget can make use of extra space, so it should
>   get as much space as possible (e.g. the horizontal direction of a
>   horizontal slider).

Set this for your `QLabel` and check how it will resize. Try other values from `QSizePolicy::Policy` enum.

Comment: This fails to provide any solution to the problem.